# Should JSON lexer be greedy?

Tags: c++, json, parsing

I am building a toy JSON parser in C++, just for the learning experience.
While building the lexer, I came across a dilemma: should the lexer be greedy? If so, where is this defined? I could not find any directive in either [JSON](https://www.json.org/) or [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).

In particular, while trying to tokenize the following (invalid number):
0.x123

Should my lexer try to parse it as the invalid number "0.x123" (greedy behavior) or the invalid number "0.x" followed by by the valid number "123" (but ultimately parsing it as an invalid sequence of tokens)?

Also, while tokenizing strings, should it be the lexer responsibility to check if the string is valid (for instance if a backslash is only followed by the allowable escape characters) or should I check this constraint in a different semantic analysis step? I guess this is more of an architectural preference, but I am curious about your opinions.

Comment: If both are invalid, does it make a difference?

Comment: _"while tokenizing strings, should it be the lexer responsibility to check if the string is valid (for instance if a backslash is only followed by the allowable escape characters)"_ -- Yes. The lexer is concerned with what the input _says_ and the parser is concerned with what the input _means._ String escape sequences, IMO, fall into the former category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invalid is invalid. If you can't parse it, bail at the earliest opportunity and raise an error.

There's no need to be greedy here because you'll just waste time processing data that has zero impact on the situation.

Comment: *"Invalid is invalid"*. In fact, it might be more complicated with how error handling is done/wanted. if we stop at first error or try to report "all" (relevant) errors... In later case, having "invalid token `0.x123`" seems better than "invalid token `0.x`" and "cannot have 2 numbers in sequence `0.x`(Error) and `123`".

Comment: @Jarod42 Usually errors are reported like "invalid token at position X (0.x123...)" where the user can figure out the details. It's really not possible to guess what happened in most cases, especially if the number is pure garbage like this. MySQL does a fantastic job of pinpointing errors in this specific way.

Comment: I just meant that is not always clear if it is a lexer error (invalid token `0.x123`) parser error (`0.` `x123`) and that lexing strategy might have influence on result.

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted because of @Jarod42 comments. I should have mentioned that I am trying to parse the file in its entirety and report all errors found. I tend to agree with Jarod42 in that it seems better to report it as a single invalid number, although I can't explain why that is.